# Limit of $\sqrt{n^2+n} - \sqrt[3]{n^3-n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to find the limit: $$\sqrt{n^2+n} - \sqrt[3]{n^3-n}$$
I tried to use the relationships $(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2) = a^3-b^3$ and $(a-b)(a+b) = a^2-b^2$ but the denominator becomes very difficult to manage.

Can you provide any hint to attack the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would rewrite it as a quotient using log-exp and apply l'Hôpital.

Comment: @Hyperplane Thank you, but i prefer a more elementary solution if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Both parts of the expression are "about $n$" for large $n$. So, you can separate the problem into finding
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n^2+n}-n$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{n^3-n}-n,$$
both of which are amenable to the relationships you wish to use.

Comment: It worked great, thank you